# Maximum non-Canon paper weight for Canon PIXMA printers?

Tags: printer, paper, canon-pixma

In the specifications of the Canon printers, such as [PIXMA MG7150](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Printers/Inkjet/PIXMA_MG7150/index.aspx#p-specification4), it is said that we should not use papers that are too thick (weighing more than 28lb or 105g/m²), except for Canon genuine paper.

How serious is this? what happens if we use heavier non-Canon media? for example 215g/m² card stock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What can go wrong?

- Paper jam can occur and possibly damage the printer.
- The paper may not move properly when printing, ruining your printout.

Canon paper probably doesn't have any unique or magical properties, it's just certified to work. That means that non-Canon paper *may* work, but you're trying it at your own responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently in the market for a new printer and pressed Canon tech support on this same question.  They said that if the use of non-Canon media caused a jam or other problem that required service, it would not be considered a warranty repair.  On that basis, I went with another brand.

Answer (score 1):

After having read in community blogs that 110 lb might work, I just printed 160 g/mm2 on my older but trusty Canon Pixma MP640 - using of course the rear tray. 
It worked well for a couple of sheets - although I did not test masses as they might leave more paper abrasives left in the printer.

The 160 g/mm2 (or gsm) would be equivalent to about 106 lb paper according to [this source](https://www.starprintbrokers.com/resources/paper-conversion/)

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question, it's not only about what kind of paper and weight, **it's about the why**, right?, well you can physically feed a max weight of "X" for different Canon printers, the reason they tell you to use only genuine Canon paper of A, B or C weight **has to do with the paper properties regarding ink absorption**.

Remember: being able to feed 100g, 120g, 140g, 160g, etc. on your printer only addresses the weight it can handle with physical parts, not the behavior or response of the paper when you are already printing, or if you are printing borderless. The thing is they don't recommend using beyond X unless it's official genuine paper because it can damage your print head. HOW? why? paper can handle so much ink, it can change weight and also curve itself actually touching the ink jet nozzles and damaging them inserting particles there. That's something you wouldn't want to happen.

So in short, use paper that your printer can handle both psychically by the printer rollers AND without touching the print head nozzles or curving when coming out, borderless printing or not.